# Calculation of temperature correction for altimeter

Tags: altimeter

I try to calculate the correction of cold temperature for altimeter , i use for this the equation 24 of the Engineering Sciences Data Unit (ESDU) publication but it give me very high number .
if i take for example the given conditions
altitude of aircraft 1000 ft
0 ft for aerodrome altitude
t0 288 K
temperature deviation from the ISA = 259.9812
L0 = 0.001981
the result is 599777.4389 ft is too big , the expected result is 60 ft So where is mistakes ?
[image]

EDIT :
So i corrected the ISA dev according to what Ralph said but the result still incorrect i joint the step of calculation :
[image]
the expected result is 60 ft
[image]

Comment: 259 degree temp dev from ISA is unreasonable by an order of magnitude. You may be mixing C and K units there. Please fix that & edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Infact 288degK at 0 ft altitude is = 15degC = ISA, so intended dev from ISA seems to be zero for purpose of the example question.

Comment: I agree, you are mixing temperature scales (K and C) and hence your incorrect result.

Comment: T aerodrome = 273K, T isa = 288K. so dT = 15K.  Applying the correct formula (see Namsters' answer below) gives 15/0.001981 * ln (1+ 1.981/288) = 51.90ft  (since dH aerodrome = 0).  

The table from PANS OPS Doc 8168 uses an approximation which works for temps above -15C  (4 times the alt above the aerodrome in thousands of feet, times dT which equals 60).

Answer (score 1):

Finaly i have found the answer the error is on all book that published the equation there is the true equation
[image]

Comment: What is the source of the original screenshot (i.e. what published the wrong equation)?

Comment: Yes the original equation is given in PANS OPS Doc 8168 Chapter 4 section 3.4

Comment: Can you specify what each variable is? I'm attempting to recreate this myself in excel. It would help greatly.